# Where are data-types for Rust (eg. float) defined?

Tags: rust

Rust is obviously a new language (0.8). It looks interesting, and I'm starting to look at it. I came across a mention of some software where `float` was changed to `f64`, so I wanted to find where the data-types, including `float` were defined. I couldn't find anything very specific. I did find:

> There are three floating-point types: `float`, `f32`, and `f64`. Floating-point numbers are written `0.0`, `1e6`, or `2.1e-4`. Like integers, floating-point literals are inferred to the correct type. Suffixes `f`, `f32`, and `f64`.

I guess "*float*" or "*f*" is 16 bit.

On a more general note (I'm no computer scientist), is it really worth messing around with all these small data-types like `int`, `int32`, `int64`, `f`, `f32`, `f64` (to name a few). I can understand some languages having eg. a byte-type, because string is a fairly complex type. For numeric-types, I think it just creates unnecessary complexity. Why not just have `i64` and `f64` and call them *int* and *float* (or `i64` and `f64` to cater for future changes, or have float and int default to these).

Perhaps there are some low-level programs that require smaller values, but why not reserve the usage to those programs that need them and leave them out of the core? I find it an unnecessary chore to convert from eg. `int` to `i64`, etc., and what does it really achieve? Alternatively, leave them in the "core", but default to the 64-bit types. The 64-bit types are obviously necessary, whereas the rest are only necessary for specific cases (IMO).

Answer (score 8):

`float`, `f32` and `f64` are defined in the Rust manual: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/rust.html#primitive-types

Specifically, for `float`:

> The Rust type float is a machine-specific type equal to one of the
>   supported Rust floating-point machine types (f32 or f64). It is the
>   largest floating-point type that is directly supported by hardware on
>   the target machine, or if the target machine has no floating-point
>   hardware support, the largest floating-point type supported by the
>   software floating-point library used to support the other
>   floating-point machine types.

So `float` is not 16-bits, it's an alias for either `f32` or `f64`, depending on the hardware.

To answer the second part of your question, in a low-language level like Rust, one can not simply postulate that a float is 64-bits, because if the hardware does not support this kind of floats natively then there is a significant performance penalty. One can neither have a single float type with an unspecified representation, because for a lot of use cases one need to have guarantees on the precision of the manipulated numbers.

In general, you would use `float` in the general case, and `f32` or `f64` when you have specific needs.

**Edit:** `float` has now been [*removed* from the language](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/9519), and there are only `f32` and `f64` float types now. The point being that all current architectures support 64-bits floats now, so `float` was always `f64`, and no use case were found for a machine-specific type.

Comment: FWIW, `float` was actually an alias for `f64` on all the platforms that Rust ran on... "was" because it was recently removed since it is pointless having two types that both always mean "64-bit floating-point number" (the removal was post-0.8, though).

Comment: Thanks all. Isn't defaulting to a size depending on hardware dangerous? I do realize that many languages do that. I guess in a few years we will all have 64-bit processors for everything. For the inconvenience of converting from one to the other, why not just default to 64-bit, and possibly in a few or so years change that to 128-bit? Software that requires it can specifically use the smaller size numbers. Alternatively, set a compiler option for specific size  numbers. If the numeric size can be specified everywhere without a default, maybe it's not the possible problem that I foresee.

Comment: @BrianOh: that's why `float` was removed. There's discussion about renaming `int` and `uint` to something like `intptr` and `uintptr` too; the basic types, in their case, do need to stay around as pointer-sized types for pointer operations, but having them as `int` and `uint` does encourage people to use them rather than the most appropriate, specific and consistent type.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone, I have amended my answer with the recent changes in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all. I still think that there is "some" merit in my argument, to default also to i64, but I'll wait until I have a bit more experience with the language before possibly putting my foot in it. I do understand that some low-level programs likely require access to a large set of small numbers.

Answer (score 6):

An answer to your "more general note": Rust exposes this variety of numeric types for two inter-related reasons:

- Rust is a systems language.

  The compilation target (LLVM, or eventually concrete machine code, such as amd64) makes these distinctions to represent different hardware capabilities.  Choosing different data types for different platforms impacts runtime performance, memory, and other resource usage.  This flexibility is exposed to the programmer to allow them to fine tune their software to particular hardware.
- Rust prioritizes interoperating with C.

  C may have made the same distinctions for the same justification, or it may have made the distinction because C is simpler when it provides *fewer* abstractions and delegates more to the underlying assembler.

  Either way, in order to interoperate between Rust and C without costly generic abstraction layers between them, the primitive types in each language correspond directly to each other.

Some advice:

If you don't care about performance, simply use the largest int, `i64` or `u64`, or float type, `f64`.  The resulting code will have easy-to-predict wrap-around and precisions behavior, but it will perform differently on different architectures, and it wastes space or time in some situations.

This *contrasts* with the conventional C wisdom (and maybe the Rust community would disagree with me), because if you use the "natural type for the architecture" the same code will perform well on multiple architectures.  I'm of the opinion, however, that unexpected differences in wrap-around or float precision are a worse problem than performance. (My bias comes from dealing with security.)

If you want to avoid wrap around completely with integers, you can use bigints, which are costly software abstractions over hardware primitives.

As an aside, I appreciate explicitly seeing `f64` as the type to remind me of precision errors.  For example, JavaScript numbers are `f64`, but it may be easy to forget that and get surprised by JS code like `var f = Math.pow(2, 53); f + 1 === f` which evaluates to `true`.  The same is true in Rust, but since I notice the type is `f64` I'm more likely to remember.

Comment: Thanks all for comments. I think I'll avoid bigints, I've seen the performance penalty elsewhere. I think that i64 and f64 are large enough for anything I'm going to use for many years (in general). I do think however there are places where specific (smaller) sizes are the default, and require alternative lines-of-code to convert types (eg. fmt!). I haven't done much with the language yet, so I cannot yet show all of the relevant places where I see extra work to work-around the small default types. I do fully understand the need for smaller types where performance/space is critical.